# Defining attributes for objects/entities in python/google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, class-design

I've seen repeated examples like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import datetime

class Book(db.Expando):
    pass

obj = Book()
obj.title = 'The Grapes of Wrath'
obj.author = 'John Steinbeck'
obj.copyright_year = 1939
obj.author_birthdate = datetime.date(1902, 2, 27)

obj.put()
```

It's the first time I've come across this sort of code, where the attributes are set **outside** of the class definition.  It strikes me as a very bad practice.  I prefer:

```
class Book(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()
    copyright_year = db.IntegerProperty()
    author_birthdate = db.DateProperty()

...
    obj = Book(title='The Grapes of Wrath', author='John Steinbeck', copyright_year=1939, author_birthdate=datetime.date(1902, 2, 27))
```

Can someone offer an assurance over the nature of the author's practice?  Where and when such a method would be acceptable?

It was mentioned that google's model for data storage allows for unusual flexibility.  I thought this example may be a poor and overly subtle introduction to that concept.  The author has actually pointed out the disadvantages of this style, yet goes on to keep repeating it.  So, there might be some advantage to it.

Comment: Programming Google App Engine, Dan Sanderson, O'Reilly/Google Press.  It's very scattered, anyone know of better books for learning google app engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html). The snippet provided is valid, although it's not clear why the class is completely empty (might be for illustrational purposes). I suppose the main question is *when to use Expando Model*?

Imagine a site collecting orders for all kinds of goods possible. One customer might want to order a kitten, another one might want to order a book, etc. A books and a kitten have very little in common, maybe just a price and weight. But we want our customers to provide details on their irders, e.g. one customer might order a kitten 3 months old, siamese, blue eyed, and another might order "Lord of The Rings" 2nd edition, hardcover, author signed, etc. Although these properties aren't relevant at the moment of collecting an order, they are vital of your business logic. Also you might process these properties later.

The only solution here is to use Expando model, because you can't create a universal class (or hierarchy of classes) covering all the existing properties. The Expando model will hold all the general properties (price, weight, tracking id, shipping cost, custom fees, etc.) and methods (calculating total, discounts, etc.), the rest of the properties will be created by the customer dynamically at runtime. A model instance will be saved into the datastore with all its properties, and any particular instance will return all the properties defined on it via Model.properties() method.

Comment: That was a very clear and short explanation, if only the author bothered to do that.

Comment: Good explanation, though I would argue not a great reason: if these properties are essential to your business logic, they should be included in the model definition somewhere.

Comment: Not really necessary. These properties are essential for fulfilling a customer's request (like the customer gets red coffee mug, not blue), they have little value from processing logic. 

Do you think it would be a misuse of Expando? What would be a better way, given that I don't know in advance neither the quantity of properties on a particular instance nor their type?

Answer (score 2):

That's funny. I read the same book and thought the same thing. I've been using App Engine Python since it launched and NEVER use Expando models.

I think the author's intent was to ease readers who may not be familiar with Python classes into the concept of defining models, but I didn't find it helpful.

One time that the datastore's flexibility came in handy for me was when I switched a field in one of my models from using DateTime to using a custom String property.  Entities with fields of both types could live side-by-side, and I could migrate them as each was accessed.

Comment: +1. I, too, have never used and Expando. It's a cool idea, and I am glad that it is there, but it's hardly what i would use to try to teach someone about GAE datastore programming.

Comment: Could recommend a better source for learning to use App Engine Python?

Comment: @shafty That's the only book I got. It helped with understanding how indexes work, and what the limitations on queries are. After that I mainly looked at Google's sample apps, and their reference documentation (packed with great code snippets). Depending on your Python experience you might want to pick up Learning Python 3rd Edition. It covers Python 2.5 nicely (and can be bought used for cheap).